# Bibliography style which extracts only the initials of the first names

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, apa-style, chicago-style

I would like the author names in the bibliography to be of the form 
"Lastname, A.B."

I thought that it is the bibliography style file like APA or Chicago which will choose only the initials of the author's first name and ignore the full name that has been typed (e.g. Andrew Middlename Lastname). All the styles tried so far do not compress the information typed in author field. Does that mean I have to enter the names in the required format only or is there some Tex solution to it?

**Edit:**
In view of the tags apa and chicago added by the moderators, my guess is that the answer can be adapted to them by using `\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,uniquename=init,firstinits,bibstyle=chicago]{biblatex}` and installing biblatex-chicago.bst file? or is there another way?

**Update:** 
In response to the answers, I would have posted this before but didn't know exactly how to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
@book{test,
  author = {Herbert Voss},
  title  = {Me, I and myself},
  year   = 2010,
  location = {Berlin}}

@ARTICLE{Name10,
  author = {{F}irstname {M}iddlename {L}astname},
  title = {{T}itle of the paper},
  journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle },
  year = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,uniquename=init,firstinits]{biblatex}
\bibliography{demo}

\begin{document}
A reference to~\cite{test}.

\cite{Name10}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to mark a code sample, highlight it an hit the button for "code sample". This is the button with "101010" on it.

Comment: I did that but doesnt seem to make a difference!

Comment: Were you able to remove the braces from the author names?

Comment: @Torbjorn: Yes, by the method suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you can use the package biblatex, it is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
@book{test,
  author = {Herbert Voss},
  title  = {Me, I and myself},
  year   = 2010,
  location = {Berlin},
  url    = {http://www.myirl.org},
  urldate= {2010-03-04},
} 
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits,url=false]{biblatex}

\bibliography{demo}

\begin{document}
A reference to~\cite{test}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert. Your example file is running but I had  to load package "csquotes" and specify [uniquename=inits] eg. \usepackage[uniquename=inits,style=authoryear,firstinits]{biblatex} as shown in the error log to get the result on my bib file but the format is not as desired. Also, it is showing all the urls and optional information which I donot want in the bibliography.

Comment: \usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits,url=false]{biblatex}

Comment: I don't know why but still not getting the Lastname, A.B. format with this method on my .bib file.

Comment: I figured it out. Its because the author names are not entered as Lastname, firstnames. Any trick for modifying the data entries?

Comment: Did you have a text editor that supports Regular Expression find/replaces?

Comment: it makes no difference, how the names are written in the bibliography data

Comment: If that is not the problem, then why is the desired format not coming? I am using Winedt as the Latex IDE. It does support regular expression search and replace.

Comment: always the same old story ... show a _complete_ minimal example, which let us see that it does not work for you, what works for me ...

Answer (score 5):

### Edit

The problem with the example you just added, is that you have curly brackets around the first letters of the names. Remove those, and you get "Lastname, F. M.". That is, your author field should be

author = {Firstname Middlename Lastname}

---

Biblatex is, I gather, "the way to go", but if you want to use e.g natbib, you can try the `agsm` style, which is from the [Harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/harvard.html) family of bibliography styles.

Adapting the example given by Herbert (I didn't know about the `filecontents`package, thanks):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
@book{test,
  author = {Herbert Voss},
  title  = {Me, I and myself},
  year   = 2010,
  location = {Berlin}} 
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}
A reference to~\cite{test}.

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{demo}
\end{document}
```

Which gives as output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Since I use Jabref for entering the info, it capitalizes what is typed in capitals. Is there a way to remove the braces automatically from the author fields only, as I would like them in the Title field? Also, is there a way to remove the "In:" which accompanies all the articles bibliography format?

Comment: You can try using Tools --> Replace String in JabRef. First, search for `{`, replace with nothing (leave that empty), and limit the search to the `author` field. Repeat for `}`. That seemed to do the trick for me.  As for your other question, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Consider making your own .bst file by running:

`latex makebst`

from the command line. You'll get an option to choose the full first name or just the initials.

Comment: and tons of other options which _must_ be answered ... ;-)